# Rest convention on put / post response?

Tags: rest

I was wondering whether there is a standard to what the response should be on a PUT / POST? For example, to give some context if I were to expose an endpoint to update / create a customer is the convention to return a:

- Status code of 200 / OK
- ***OR*** return all the data back that was saved back to the user. In essence returning the request back but with identity values set?

Of course any links to credible sites would be fantastic and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What about these:

[POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5):

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header

[PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6):

> If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No
>   Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful
>   completion of the request.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the links made an interesting read although they don't mention anything against what (if anything) should be returned in the body of the response. I imagine this is personal convention and whether the API should return a heavy payload.